# Set template data globally in Slim v3

Tags: php, slim

I've recently started building a new application with the updated Slim framework in version 3.

I usually have a few variables that I want available in every template (like username, date, etc.). In Slim v2, I used to do this by using a hook and then calling the [setData or appendData](http://docs.slimframework.com/view/data/) methods like so:

```
$app->view->setData(array(
    'user' => $user
));
```

Hooks have been replaced by Middlewares in v3, I however do not know how to set the data on the view globally for all templates - any ideas?

Comment: what is the type of view engine you are using? is it PHP-View or Twig-View?

Comment: I'm using Smarty-View currently, I would not mind switching though - not many templates yet and I merely used it cause I used it before

Comment: Cool, actually I made my answer according the 2 basic components of Slim 3, PHP-View and Twig-View http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is really according to the *view* component you are using, Slim 3 project provide 2 components [Twig-View](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View) and [PHP-View](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View)

For *Twig-View*, you can use *offsetSet*, this is a basic [usage example](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View#usage), I'm going to use that example, but with one additional line to set *foo* variable into the *view*

```
$container['view'] = function ($c) {
    // while defining the view, you are passing settings as array
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('path/to/templates', [
    'cache' => 'path/to/cache'
    ]);

    // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension
    $basePath = rtrim(str_ireplace('index.php', '', $c['request']->getUri()->getBasePath()), '/');
    $view->addExtension(new Slim\Views\TwigExtension($c['router'], $basePath));

    //////////////////////////////
    // this is my additional line
    $view->offsetSet('foo', 'bar');
    //////////////////////////////

    return $view;
};
```

You can access that in Twig template simply by using

```
{{ foo }}
```

For *PHP-View*, it has different forms of passing variables to template, you can find them in [here](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View#template-variables)

```
// via the constructor
$templateVariables = [
    "title" => "Title"
];
$phpView = new PhpRenderer("./path/to/templates", $templateVariables);

// or setter
$phpView->setAttributes($templateVariables);

// or individually
$phpView->addAttribute($key, $value);
```

Answer (score 5):

For twig-view

`$view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal($name, $value);`